# How can i insert only unique rows into SQL Server Database table with threadpoolexecutor?

Tags: python, sql-server, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

So basically, i am doing an api call and trying to store the extracted dataframe in a SQL Server database table.

The problem is that the table already has some data in it and i want only the unique rows to get written in the table which is somehow not happening. I am using threadpoolexecutor to speed up the api call process. Everything works fine if the table is empty but if there some rows already there in the table then it won't write anything at all.

What would be the fastest way to write unique rows in the SQL server database? Should i go with pandas/SQL operations to do this?

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from bidspipe.utils import blp
from bidspipe.config import conn, session, engine
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy as sa
import time
import itertools
import concurrent.futures
from csv import writer


def api_call(value):

    global df_api
    df_api = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in value:
        UID = df_dictionary.values[i][0]
        ticker = df_dictionary.values[i][1]
        yellowbutton = df_dictionary.values[i][2]
        field = df_dictionary.values[i][3]
        periodicity = df_dictionary.values[i][6]

        ts = blp.BLP().bdh(
            strSecurity=f'{ticker} {yellowbutton}',
            strData=field,
            startdate=startdate,
            enddate=datetime.today() - timedelta(1),
            periodicity=periodicity
        )

        ts.reset_index(inplace=True)
        ts.insert(0,'UID',UID)
        ts = ts.rename(columns={ts.columns[1]:'AsOfDateTime',ts.columns[2]:'Price'})
       
        ts.to_sql('prices', schema ='dbo', con = engine, chunksize= None , if_exists='append', index=False)
   

if __name__ == "__main__":

    test_runs = 1
    for i in range(0, test_runs):
        print("\n\nLoop: ",i+1)
        df_dictionary = pd.read_sql_table('dictionary', conn)
        startdate = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
        t1 = time.perf_counter()
        seq = list(range(0, len(df_dictionary)))
        values = list(itertools.zip_longest(*[iter(seq)] * 2))
        print("\nNo. of threads:", len(values))

        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
            executor.map(api_call, values)
            executor.shutdown(wait=True)
            

        t2 = time.perf_counter()
        finish_time.append(t2-t1)
        print(f'Finished in {t2-t1} seconds')

   

    conn.close()
```

Comment: I think the fastest way will be to create a temporary table in SQL and then do an SQL MERGE statement. Using Pandas would require pulling the data into memory to compare if the values exist. Other DBs have UPSERT functionality that would allow you to ignore insert duplicates. I believe the closest operation to that in SQL Server is the MERGE statement which requires a two tables (source and destination).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: Hi Jason, thanks for your answer. I actually performed a similar thing i.e. to create a temporary table in the Server Database and then performed "WHERE NOT EXISTS" query to get only unique rows in the destination table. So far it's giving me insane write speeds but I'm just skeptical about similar performance when the destination table size grows. I read somewhere that "NOT EXISTS" command might fail with a million rows. Do you think merge would be a better option than not exists?

Comment: Not necessarily, MERGE will just give you more options in case you want to update or delete records. In general I think the SQL temporary table approach with "NOT EXISTS", or "INNER JOIN", or "MERGE" will be the best performance.

Comment: Thanks Jason. So far "NOT EXISTS" is giving me the best performance and have decided to go with that. Cheers!